# how to display a new created object on both devices in Unity networking?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, spawn

I am working on a network game with Unity3D network. I am new to network programming.

Let's say I created objects and attached them to the player (either on server or client). I need to keep displaying those objects on another device. I've seen many materials, but I haven't found a solution yet.

It seems NetworkServer.Spawn is a way to do it. Is that right and any other better way? Give some advice to this novice^^ Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NetworkServer.Spawn you need to register your prefab in your NetworkManager.

If you're not expecting anyone new to join your server you can also use Command and ClientRPC that will spawn this prefab and parent it to correct game object on every client.

Comment: I guess I need to study more about Command & ClientPRC. Networking really confuses me. Thank you for your reply^^

Answer (score 1):

Only server/host can spawn network-synched GameObjects.

```
// put this component on a prefab you wish to spawn
class MyNetworkedObject : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SyncVar]
    public int myHealth;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("My health is: " + myHealth);
    }
}

// put this component on an empty GameObject somewhere in the scene and check "Server Only" on its NetworkIdentity
class MySpawner : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public MyNetworkedObject myPrefab;

    void OnValidate()
    {
        if (GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().serverOnly == false)
            Debug.LogWarning("This component wants NetworkIdentity to have \"Server Only\" checked (for educational purposes, not an actual requirement).");
    }

    public void SpawnObject(int withHealth)
    {
        if (!isServer)
            throw new Exception("Only server may call this! It wouldn't have any effect on client.");

        MyNetworkedObject newObject = Instantiate(myPrefab);
        // setup newObject here, before you spawn it
        newObject.myHealth = withHealth;

        NetworkServer.Spawn(newObject.gameObject);
    }
}
```

As Fiffe already mentioned, the prefab must be registered inside your NetworkManager for it to be spawnable. Also, all networked objects must have a NetworkIdentity component.

Once the object is spawned by the server, server will tell all connected clients to spawn the object with current values of any SyncVars, and also on any clients that might connect later. If SyncVars change on the server, server will tell all connected clients to change the value accordingly.

If you want clients to invoke the spawning of an object, the easiest way is to go with Local Authority:

```
// put this component on the player prefab that you already assigned to NetworkManager.PlayerPrefab
class MyNetworkedPlayerObject : NetworkBehaviour
{
    void OnValidate()
    {
        if (GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().localPlayerAuthority == false)
            Debug.LogWarning("This component requires NetworkIdentity to have \"Local Player Authority\" checked.");
    }

    public void RequestSpawnObject(int withHealth)
    {
        if (!hasAuthority)
            throw new Exception("Only the player owned by this client may call me.");

        // the following call will magically execute on the server, even though it was called on the client
        CmdSpawnObject(withHealth);
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdSpawnObject(int withHealth)
    {
        // this code will always run on the server
        FindObjectOfType<MySpawner>().SpawnObject(withHealth);
    }
}
```

Each client can have one or more networked objects with Local Player Authority. Each networked object is either owned by server, or by exactly one client that has Local Player Authority for that object. Client may invoke Commands only on objects that **that client has Local Player Authority on**. Commands are invoked by the client, but executed on the server. This execution will happen asynchronously, client can not know when the server will execute it. Thus, Commands can have parameters, but no return value.

Also:

- If you want all clients to execute a method on a networked object, server can invoke `[ClientRPC]` methods on any networked object, which will then execute on the clients. If a client connects later, it will **not** invoke rpc calls that happened before the client connected.
- Even clients with Local Player Authority can not change SyncVars. If they do, server and other clients will not receive the changes. Only server can change SyncVars and have it synchronized to the clients
- Transform is a special case. Objects can have a NetworkTransform component which allows **owning** client (or server) to control the position and rotation of that object and have it synched to server and other clients. Same with NetworkAnimator.
- If you want to decide at runtime whether the server or the client have authority over an object, you must have a prefab for either case, one with "Local Player Authority" checked, one without. Server can never be owner of an object that has "Local Player Authority" checked (but local client on a host can).
- Clients can send messages to the server and vice versa.

I hope this gives you a short overview.